# Javascript textarea word count not enabling submit button

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I am trying to make it so that when the user types more than 10 words into the textarea the submit button is enabled. Below is my code exerpt. It's not letting me submit even when there are 10+ words in there. Any help would be appreciated.

```
            <?php
                    if($auth = 1)
                    {
                        echo "<center><h1>Write Article</h1><br /></center>";
                        echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"processarticle.php\" id=\"myform\" >";
                        echo "<b>Keywords:</b> " . $array['keywords'];
                        echo "<br />";
                        echo "<b>Purpose:</b> " . $array['purpose'];
                        echo "<br />";
                        echo "<b>Style:</b> " . $array['style'];
                        echo "<br />";
                        echo "<b>Instructions:</b> " . $array['instructions'];
                        echo "<br />";
                        echo "<b>Length:</b> " . $array['length'];
                        echo "<br />";
                        echo "<hr>";
                        echo "<textarea rows=35 cols=85 name=\"content\">";
                        echo "</textarea>";
                        echo "<br />";
                        echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"refferer\" value=\"1\" />";
                        echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"articleid\" value=\"" . $arid . "\" />";
                        echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"articletitle\" value=\"" . $articletitle . "\" />";
                        echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit Article\" id=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" />";
                        echo "</form>";
                    }

                ?>
                <br /><br /><br />
                <!-- /main -->
                </div>


            <!-- content -->
            </div>

        <!-- /content-out -->
        </div>

        <!-- footer -->
        <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/footer.php'); ?>
        </body>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $('#myform').submit(function(event) {
                    var text = $("#content").val();
                    text = text.split(" ");
                    // check for at least 10 words
                    if(text.length < 10){
                        // prevent submit
                        event.preventDefault();
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            </script>
```

Comment: Your `<script type="text/javascript">...</script>` should be either inside your `<head>...</head>` or your `<body>...</body>`. In your code you have it outside of the body. You cannot do this.

Comment: i just updated the code check once..

Answer (score 1):

You have used `#content` but you didn't define any `id` for your text area. Define an ID and access it. Add an `id` attribute like this,

```
echo "<textarea rows=35 cols=85 name=\"content\" id=\"content\">";
```

Comment: I've added an id to the text area but it still doesn't work :/

Comment: @KriiV, among all the problems in the code, this is the one that prevents the logic from working. So check whether you actually made the suggested correction. (Alternatively, if there is only one textarea element on the page, you would not need the `id` attribute and could use just `$("textarea")` instead of `$("#content")`.)

Answer (score 1):

you had not defined the content as Id ..
declare `#content` as id of text area..

```
"<textarea rows=35 cols=85 name=\"content\" id=\"content\">";
```

//finding the words count..

```
String input = $('content').val();
String[] elements = input.split(" ");

if(elements.length>10){
//your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a listener on the form, and the textarea has a name, you can read the value of the textarea as:

```
    var text = this.content.value;
```

.

```
    text = text.split(" ");

    // check for at least 10 words
    if(text.length < 10){
```

This will really only check if there are 10 spaces, if you want to check for something that looks more like a word, then look for strings of word characters:

```
    var words = text.match(/\b\w+\b/g);
```

which will split on strings of word characters, then;

```
    if (words && words.length < 10) { 
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = encodeURIComponent($("#content").val());
```